# Are you able to apply Azure Information Protection on Azure Data Lake or Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-information-protection

I'm wanting to know if you can apply Azure Information Protection on files that are in Azure Data Lake or Blob storage.

I cant seem to find any documentation that confirms this.

Cheers
Tim

Comment: There is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Information-Protection-Samples#ipcazureapp), but not sure if it can solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @IvanYang this looks like what we need  "This sample demonstrate how to use Azure Information Protection SDK in Azure application to protect data in Azure Blob Storage." Not alot of information on how to use it though

Comment: Please raise this issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-rmsdocs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%2244a2f2ce-c32f-9870-863e-5635f7e2b22d%22&in=body).